# Unable to signup using Keycloak through Cypress

Tags: java, keycloak, cypress

In my application, user management is done through [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/). While testing my application end-to-end through [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/), I came across an issue. When I sign up a user, it gives the following error:

> **We're sorry. An error has occurred, please login again through your application**.

Cypress is adding something to a generated URL after I click the submit button, which is causing this issue. The same scenario tested through [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) ran fine. I have noticed Cypress is appending `session_code` to the request URL. While doing manual testing, I don't get `session_code`.

Below is the URL generated through Cypress:

```
.../login-actions/registration?session_code=LsZbmsVVLwEH9s-xwFJ2JdDtaCu1_xzqAGOQCpjxGJI&execution=06fac3bb-fb19-474b-8659-2572586ae371&client_id=web_app&tab_id=PSlmfgdv0ls
```

Where as a manually generated URL is like following:

```
.../login-actions/registration?client_id=web_app&tab_id=PSlmfgdv0ls
```

My application backend is [Spring Boot](http://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) and the front-end is in [React](https://reactjs.org/) and [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/).

It would be really helpful if anyone could guide us through this issue. Please let me know if you need more information about our application.

Answer (score 0):

The [Keycloak Authenticator](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.1/javadocs/org/keycloak/authentication/Authenticator.html) documentation explains that the `authenticate` method checks the current HTTP request to determine if authentication requirements have been satisfied, and, if not, a challenge response is sent back.  If the challenge response itself is authentication, then you'll see a URL with the `session_code` parameter.

It goes on to say that `session_code`, in the first URL example, pertains to the code generated from [AuthenticationFlowContext.generateAccessCode()](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.1/javadocs/org/keycloak/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationFlowContext.html#generateAccessCode--), which further explains:

> **String generateAccessCode()**
>
> Generates access code and updates `clientsession` timestamp. Access codes must be included in form action callbacks as a query parameter.

However, the "manually" generated URL, that does not include the `session_code` parameter, seems to indicate that the initial registration of the client has been successful and a client configuration endpoint is being used to make a GET request - a client read request - and all is well.  Everything works fine.

Therefore, it seems that Cypress is being sent a challenge response ([and potentially exposing a security flaw in your application](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Insecure-Content)). Possible reasons for this might be further explained within Cypress's documentation on [Web Security](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html).

[Common Workarounds](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Common-Workarounds) might provide you with a remedy, or, if all else fails, you might try [Disabling Web Security](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Disabling-Web-Security) for testing purposes as well.